# jQuery UI Draggable - Retain drag-ability after drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a list of items. I want to drag a clone of an item from the list to a table - so far so good.

When the item is dragged to the table I would like to be able to drag that item to a different cell in the table. I am hoping someone can help with this. The code I have so far is as follows:-

```
$('.drag').draggable({
      cursor:'move',     
      helper:'clone'
});

$('.dog_drop').droppable( {
      drop: handleDropEvent   
  } );

function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
  var draggable = ui.draggable;
  $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo($(this)),      
  // ajax in here
}
```

I would be very grateful for any advice you can provide.

Many thanks in advance
Phill

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the new appended item and run draggable() function on it.

For example if the .drag item is a link you can do the following:

```
$('.drag').draggable({
  find: '.dog_drop',
  cursor:'move'
});

$('.dog_drop').droppable( {
    drop: handleDropEvent
  } );

function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.append(ui.draggable);

    $('.dog_drop').find('div:last').draggable({
      cursor:'move'
    });  

  // ajax in here
}
```

Make sure to select the last item so it can work with multiple items.

Comment: Nabil, this is excellent, thank you so much for taking the time to response. The issue I have now is that I wanted to actually move the element to a new cell, not clone it. When I change 'clone' to 'original', I get some very strange behaviour. I'm sure this is to do the handleDropEvent function but have no idea how to deal with it. Any further assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You're quite welcome @Phill, so you want to be able to drag the item from the list to cell1 ... and then drag the same item from the original list to cell2 ? if that's what you want there are two ways to do this ... you can keep using the clone object and use revert as well to return the item to the original list ... or you can recreate the item in the list. if that's what you are looking for i will update the answer for you.

Comment: Hi Nabil. What I want to do is drag an item from the list to cell 1. Then move the item from cell1 to cell2. In this case the item will disappear from cell 1 and appear in cell2.

Comment: Updated my answer.. i haven't tested the code but it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks again Nabil. I'm afraid this doesn't work at all. The item disappears from the list and doesn't drop into the dog_drop box.

Your original answer was so close, it's just that I wanted to be able to drag the item from one cell to another - does that make sense? Sorry, and thank you for your patience.

Comment: No problem phill i'm happy to help, could you send me your whole code please.

Comment: That's very kind Nabil. I will put this on jFiddle today (although I did try this before and it wouldn't work at all - my lack of experience I'm sure). Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Nabil, I have added the code to jsfiddle here;- https://jsfiddle.net/krb5smwx/4/. All the best. Phill